# On the two definition of weakly convergence of measures, which one is true?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a metric space and $\mu, \mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots$ Borel probability mesures on $X$. I met the following two definitions of the weakly convergence of $\{\mu_n\}$:

**1**. We call $\{\mu_n\}$ converges weakly to $\mu$ if $\int f d\mu_n\to \int fd\mu$ for any $f\in C(X)$, where $C(X)=\{f:X\to R: \text{$f$ is continuous and bounded}\}$;

**2.** We call $\{\mu_n\}$ converges weakly to $\mu$ if $\int f d\mu_n\to \int fd\mu$ for any $f\in C_c(X)$, where $C_c(X)=\{f:X\to R: \text{$f$ is continous and has compact support}\}$.

But, generally speaking, $C_c(X)$ and $C(X)$ are not necessarily equal on a metric space. So, which one is true? Or, these are actually two different definitions with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not equivalent. In K L Chung's book the second one is called vague convergence. The first definition is the standard one.